# How to perform operations in case of negative numbers?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calculator

I wanted to build a calculator app for android and for that I needed a parser to convert string expressions to be solved. Now Java and Kotlin doesn't support eval function and importing a javascript engine just for sake of an operation can open me up to various vulnerabilities. So I made my own calculator parser. Now it's working completely fine, all arithmetic operations are working fine except in negative numbers in crash. I do know what the problem is as I am splitting the string using delimiters which are mathematical symbols but I'm not able to do any operation in negative values.

Input : -5+5  Expected : 0  Output : Exception (numberFormatException)

Here's the kotlin class :

```
    class CalculatorParser(private var expression: String) {

    init {
        if (expression.isEmpty() || expression == "0") {
            expression = "0+0"
        } else if (expression.split("+", "-", "*", "/", "^").size == 1) {
            expression = "$expression+0"
        }
    }

    private val splitStr = expression.split("+", "-", "*", "/", "^").toMutableList()
    private val a = splitStr[0].toFloat()
    private val b = splitStr[1].toFloat()
    private val operator = getDelimiter(expression)

    private fun getDelimiter(str: String): String {
        return if (str.contains("+")) {
            "+"
        } else if (str.contains("-")) {
            "-"
        } else if (str.contains("*")) {
            "*"
        } else if (str.contains("^")) {
            "^"
        } else {
            "/"
        }
    }

    private fun calculate(): Float {
        return when (operator) {
            "+" -> a + b
            "-" -> a - b
            "*" -> a * b
            "/" -> a / b
            "^" -> pow(a.toInt(), b.toInt()).toFloat()
            else -> {
                return 0f
            }
        }
    }

    fun eval(result: Float = calculate()): String {
        var final = ""
        if (result.toString().contains(".")) {
            val splitResult = result.toString().split(".")
            final = if (splitResult[1].toInt() > 0) {
                result.toString()
            } else {
                result.toInt().toString()
            }
        }
        println(splitStr) // This print statement is only for testing the split array in console to be deleted in production code.
        return final
    }

    private fun pow(base: Int, power: Int): Int {
        var result = base
        var i = 1
        while (i < power) {
            result *= base
            i++
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private val splitStr = expression.split("+", "-", "*", "/", "^").toMutableList()
 private val a = splitStr[0].toFloat()
```

the problem because of these lines when you are splitting for "-" and you write -5+5 it is splitting for - and first element is empty ("")and according to [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numberformatexception-in-java-with-examples/) when you try to parse empty string to float this leads to number format exception.And to solve that maybe you can check if first element is "-" you can convert that expression to "5-5"and that will give you result.

The key is here.You should not use "+""-" ... as first element in your expression.Beacuse you can not convert to empty string ("") to float.I hope my explanation was clear.

Comment: One way to solve this would be to generate your `expression` string with commas separating the inputs from the user. Then you just split the string on commas